# Blazor WASM: one way data binding to property of nullable object

Tags: data-binding, blazor-webassembly

Suppose you have something like this:

```
public record Test(string Name);
```

And that you need to bind the value from a "nullable" property on your page like this:

```
<InputText Value="@T?.Name"
           ValueExpression="@( () => T.Name)"

@code{

private Test? T; //gets initialized later in some cases...
}
```

Unfortunately, this won't work when `T` doesn't reference a valid reference (ie, when it's set to null) because `FieldIdentifier` only supports simple member expressions:

```
rit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The provided expression contains a UnaryExpression which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.
System.ArgumentException: The provided expression contains a UnaryExpression which is not supported. FieldIdentifier only supports simple member accessors (fields, properties) of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.ParseAccessor[Nullable`1](Expression`1 accessor, Object& model, String& fieldName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.Create[Nullable`1](Expression`1 accessor)
...
```

Removing the `ValueExpression' isn't possible because I'm using one way binding only:

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputNumber`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]] requires a value for the 'ValueExpression' parameter. Normally this is provided automatically when using 'bind-Value'.
```

Ok, I can work around this by adding a new property which accesses the property when `T` isn't null, but it's kind of weird having to do this only for one-way binding...can anyone explain why Blazor decided to take this approach?

Thanks.